# Error when I start nginx service with Phusion Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, passenger

I use Linux Server 14.04. Ruby 2.x and Rails 4.x with Phusion Passenger. For some reason I get the next error:

> 014/12/16 17:49:51 [alert] 19857#0: Unable to start the Phusion
>   Passenger watchdog because it encountered the following error during
>   startup: Unable to start the Phusion Passenger logging agent: it seems
>   to have crashed during startup for an unknown reason, with exit code
>   127 (-1: Unknown error)

I still have no idea what could have happened. And, when I try to access my web application I get the error **403 Forbidden**.
I've checked the log of nginx and I only appears that nginx can not access the files.
However, I conclude that the error is because of that message that appears when I start nginx service.
What do you think? What things could cause the error that I have?
Sorry for my english.

Comment: Check of passenger is installed properly or you can reinstall. gem install 'passenger'. Also check if the ruby versions are available at the mentioned path

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The libcurl development headers are the true issue.

Excute: `$ apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev`

I hope this helps someone else out there!